# oracle SQL: get every 2nd value of a string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substr

I am searching for a way to get every 2nd value of a string via SQL.
My string looks like this:
    12:115:22:98
and I would like to get every 2nd value out of it, in this case 115 and 98.

Tried around with regexp_substr, but best I could do was to get every value with this:

```
select regexp_substr('3:113:1:14','[^ :]+', 2, level)
        from dual
connect by regexp_substr('3:113:1:14','[^ :]+', 2, level) 
        is not null;
```

or just the 2nd value with this:

```
select regexp_substr('3: 113:1:14','[^ :]+', 2, 1)
        from dual;
```

Is there a way or maybe another function to get this to work?

Thanks in advance,
Wod

edit:

it would also be possible to make the string look like this:

```
4-116:3-113:22-12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were already so very very close...

```
select * from(
select regexp_substr('3:113:1:14:5:6:7:8','[^ :]+', 2, level), level lvl
        from dual
connect by regexp_substr('3:113:1:14:5:6:7:8','[^ :]+', 2, level) 
        is not null
) where mod(lvl,2)=1;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the fast reply, works fine (and i like the idea behind it, because it looks so simple :) )

Answer (score 0):

Using the normal `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` :

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT '12:115:22:98' STR FROM DUAL
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT '3:113:1:14' FROM DUAL
  5    )
  6  SELECT SUBSTR(STR, INSTR(STR,':',1,1)+1, INSTR(STR,':',1,2)-INSTR(STR,':',1,1)-1)
  7    ||'-'
  8    || SUBSTR(STR, INSTR(STR,':',1,3)+1)
  9    ||':'
 10    ||str str
 11  FROM data
 12  /

STR
--------------------------------------
115-98:12:115:22:98
113-14:3:113:1:14
```